# Simplify a proposition

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I can not come up with anything concrete,

$$ [\overline{(p  \wedge q)} \wedge r] \vee   [p \wedge \overline{( q  \wedge r)}]  \Leftrightarrow \,  ?    $$

Thanks!

Comment: What counts as simplification? Would a disjunction of conjunctions count, for instance?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I want to find a equivalent expression

Comment: I know, but there are infinitely many equivalent expressions. What *kind* of equivalent expression would count for you as a simplification? For instance, would you consider $$(\overline p\land r)\lor(\overline q\land r)\lor(p\land\overline q)\lor(p\land\overline r)$$ a simplification?

Comment: I suspect a typo in the original question. Would you double-check?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott yes, but i want to find a truth value for the proposition.

Comment: You can’t: its truth value depends on the truth values of $p,q$, and $r$. It’s false when $p,q$, and $r$ are all true or all false, and it’s also false when $q$ is true and $p$ and $r$ are false; in all other cases it’s true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I'll use negation $\lnot$: $\lnot (p \land q)$ to denote $\overline{(p\land q)}$, etc.

So First let me write the equivalent expression  to your expression, using $\lnot$ (the lhs of $\equiv$).

$$[\lnot(p\land q)] \land r] \lor [p \land \lnot (q \land r)]\equiv [\overline{(p  \wedge q)} \wedge r] \vee   [p \wedge \overline{( q  \wedge r)}]   $$

We need **DeMorgan's twice**: e.g., $\lnot (p \land q) \iff \lnot p \lor \lnot q, \quad $ or $$\overline{(p \land q)} \iff \overline p \lor \overline q$$

We need the ***Distributive rule*** twice: $(\lnot p\lor \lnot q) \land r \iff (\lnot p \land r) \lor (\lnot q \land r)\quad $ Or

$$ (\overline p \lor \overline q)\land r \iff (\overline p \land r) \lor (\overline q \land r)$$

That get's us to, using your notation:

$$(\overline p\land r)\lor(\overline q\land r)\lor(p\land\overline q)\lor(p\land\overline r)$$

This is in *[**disjunctive normal form**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form)*.

There are many expressions that can be equivalent to this; what exactly counts as simplified, needs more specification.

If you need to determine the *truth-value* of the proposition, then you need to use something like a *truth-table* to determine and show the values of all possible 8 truth-value assignments of $p, q, r$. That is, your proposition is not "inherently true" for all $p, q, r$ (it is not a tautoloty), nor is it inherently false (it is not a contradiction).

Comment: Then, i can not find a smaller expression that you give me

Comment: No, not really (it depends what counts as "smaller"). We cannot eliminate anything without losing vital "information). But disjunctive normal form *is* one of the standard forms used for representing propositions.  But if the following looks "smaller" by all means, use it! $$(p \lor r) \land \lnot(p\land q\land r)\iff (p \lor r)\land \overline{(p \land q \land r)}$$ It does make it a little easier to determine which truth value assignments make the proposition true, and which make it false. Just be sure you know how to *arrive at it*! ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: Nice work! +1

Comment: P.M.O. Have you ever used a truth-table to find all combinations of truth-values that make a statement true, and create propositions from this? That is one route to obtaining disjunctive normal form, and the alternative, second equivalence stated in comments above.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the following equivalent form counts as a simplification, but I like it: $(p\lor r)\land\neg(p\land q\land r)$.

Comment: yes, but how you found it?

Comment: How I found it: I imagined drawing a Venn diagram, and noticed that  the first half of your formula says that $r$ is true but not all of $p,q,r$ are true.  The second half is very similar, except it has $p$ in the role of $r$. So the whole formula says one of these two situations obtains: $p$ or $r$ (or both) must be true, but not all three of $p,q,r$.